# "only assignment call increment decrement await and new object expressions can be used as a statement" error in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

What is the problem?
"only assignment call increment decrement await and new object expressions can be used as a statement"
Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerMovement movement;


    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo) 
    {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle") 
        {
            movement.enabled = false;
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot parenthesis  `FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C# language reference on [Compiler Error CS0201](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0201):

> The compiler generates an error when it encounters an invalid statement. An invalid statement is any line or series of lines ending in a semicolon that does not represent an assignment (=), method call (), new, -- or ++ operation.

If `GameManager.EndGame` is a method, then you just need to call it in order to resolve this error:

```
FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
```